# iOS: "502 Bad Gateway. The server returned an invalid or incomplete response."

Tags: php, ios, upload, gateway

I am getting this error when I try to upload picture to php server. Do you have any idea what the problem is? Is it caused by the app or by the web server? Here's my code for uploading the picture and some strings. The interesting part is that if I try to upload video - there's no problem. When I try to upload pictures - bad gateway.

```
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];

    //NSString *urlString = @"http://pik.bg/add_android_pics.php?id=127718";
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://pik.bg/news/edit_news_android/%@", uniqueID];
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestUpload = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    //NSMutableURLRequest *requestUpload = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
    [requestUpload setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [requestUpload setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


    NSString *boundary = @"AaB03x";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [requestUpload addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        //now lets create the body of the post

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:heading.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:text.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    if (camera == YES || gallery == YES)
    {
        NSString *fileNameOne = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"uploadedImageOne.jpg"];
        NSString *imgPathWithFileNameOne = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameOne];
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(savedImage, 90) writeToFile:imgPathWithFileNameOne atomically:YES];

        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imgPathWithFileNameOne];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file1\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        if (secondImage != nil)
        {
            NSString *fileNameTwo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"uploadedImageTwo.jpg"];
            NSString *imgPathWithFileNameTwo = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameTwo];
            [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(secondImage, 90) writeToFile:imgPathWithFileNameTwo atomically:YES];

            NSData *imageDataTwo = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imgPathWithFileNameTwo];

            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file2\"; filename=\"image2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageDataTwo]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }

        if (thirdImage != nil)
        {
            NSString *fileNameThree = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"uploadedImageThree.jpg"];
            NSString *imgPathWithFileNameThree = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameThree];
            [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thirdImage, 90) writeToFile:imgPathWithFileNameThree atomically:YES];

            NSData *imageDataThree = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imgPathWithFileNameThree];

            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file3\"; filename=\"image3.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageDataThree]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }
    }

    if (video == YES)
    {
        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoString];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video_mp4\"; filename=\"%@.mp4\"\r\nContent-Type: video/mp4\r\n\r\n", uniqueName] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"submit\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [requestUpload setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestUpload returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSString *returnStringer = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog (@"Return String: %@", returnStringer);
```

I think the problem is not in my app, what do you think?

Comment: 1. I might be missing something but I don't see any BASE64 encoding of your data 
2. `[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];` ? Why not just `[body appendData:imageData];`?

Comment: Why do I have to use base64 encoding? It uploads video, it uploads one picture sometimes, but never three. I don't think the problem is in my code? Or it is?

Comment: Because multipart/form-data uses MIME and MIME uses BASE64 encoding for non ASCII data. More information at http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Comment: But my data encoding is NSASCIIStringEconding? And if that is the problem, why it uploads the video? Or a single image sometimes?